# Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false).logout(); Not Navigate to the Sign In page only After Page transition

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

provider.logout(); is normally navigate to the sign in page on pres from home.

sign in page-> signed in to Home-> signed out   -This is working fine.

but when I do some activity on home page and then click on logout-it wont navigate to the sign in page.

sign in page-> signed in to Home->activity(going other page and come back)-> signed out -getting error.

Please support to solve the issue.

please see the reference codes below.
Thanks

**Home Page**

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed:() {
final provider =Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
provider.logout();

// Navigator.push(
//   context,
//   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpWidget()),
// );

    },
    child: Text('logout')
),
```

**Google Sign In page**

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  // final user1=FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  // FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  //
  // late DatabaseReference _dbref;





  Future googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) return;
      _user = googleUser;
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      // _creatDB();



    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Future logout() async{
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

I tried with adding Navigation page rout but didn't work .